# Root Provider for Recursive @SkipSelf Components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, tree, hierarchy

I'm trying to visualize the Angular dependency injection system. Based on the documentation, it appears that the component instance tree is walked to find the first instance of the named provider, [prioritizing ElementInjector over ModuleInjector](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules).

> When a component declares a dependency, Angular tries to satisfy that dependency with its own ElementInjector. If the component's injector lacks the provider, it passes the request up to its parent component's ElementInjector.
>
> **The requests keep forwarding up until Angular finds an injector that can handle the request or runs out of ancestor ElementInjectors.**

This is not the behavior I'm observing in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pabwp5), though. In this example I've created three components, `HelloComponent`, `HelloTwoComponent`, and `HelloThreeComponent`, and these components are part of a hierarchy that follows their respective order:

```
(HelloComponent)
       |
       v
(HelloTwoComponent)
       |
       v
(HelloThreeComponent)
```

A single provider instance of `SampleService` should be created at `HelloComponent`. Using the `@SkipSelf()` modifier, `HelloTwoComponent` should inject the instance created by it's parent `HelloComponent`. Using the `@SkipSelf()` modifier again in `HelloThreeComponent` should start the dependency search at `HelloTwoComponent`, find nothing, then find the original provider in `HelloComponent`. In other words, all components in the tree should use the provider created for the root node.

```
(HelloComponent) << CREATE PROVIDER A
       |
       v
(HelloTwoComponent) << USE PROVIDER A FROM PARENT
       |
       v
(HelloThreeComponent) << USE PROVIDER A FROM GRANDPARENT
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this ended up being improper use of the `providers` property in the `@Component` annotation. It should only be present in the **root** component, like in [this fork from the original example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvvgga).

Here's a simplified example if something ever happens to the StackBlitz:

`HelloComponent`

```js
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [SampleService]
})
export class HelloComponent {
    constructor(
        private _sample: SampleService
    ) {}

}
```

`HelloTwoComponent`

```js
@Component({
    ...
})
export class HelloTwoComponent {
    constructor(
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() private _sample: SampleService
    ) {}
}
```

`HelloThreeComponent`

```js
@Component({
    ...
})
export class HelloComponent {
    constructor(
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() private _sample: SampleService
    ) {}

}
```